# Nuget does not update to lastest version in project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I use the `Nuget` package manager in VS and for some reason, the Version in `Nuget` is not updating the dll in my project. In the below image, you can see I have the latest version from Nuget, but the version in my project is incorrect. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Looking at the path in the Properties window it seems to be finding log4net in the GAC and not from the NuGet package. I would remove log4net from the GAC.

Comment: This seemed to fix the issue, but I won't be sure until my co-worker does an update/commit via TFS. Make it an answer because it seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the path in the Properties window it seems to be finding log4net in the GAC and not from the NuGet package. I would remove log4net from the GAC. Visual Studio should then use log4net from the packages directory.